# insert taking too long

Tags: postgresql, jpa, ejb, jboss7.x

My setup is: JBOSS AS 7.1.1 and PostGreSql

When there are no or very less (a couple of hundred) records in the table, my inserts/updates completes very fast.
But when the number of records get to a couple of thousand, the inserts or updates take an extremely long time. For ex: inserting a record takes more than 1 or 2 seconds.

Not sure where the problem is or where to start.

My code to update the database looks like this -

```
public long updateRecord(long id, List<MyData> myDataList) {
    Event eventFromDB = findById(id).get(0);
    List<MyData> myDataListFromDB = eventFromDB.getMyData();
    for(MyData myData : myDataList) {
        myDataListFromDB.add(myData);
    }
    em.merge(eventFromDB);
    return myDataList.size();
}
```

I am a newbie and have set up the jboss as to the best of my knowledge.

I haven't done any configuration settings on either the JBOSS AS or the PostGreSQL.

The JBOSS AS is running in the standalone mode using the standalone-full.xml config file.

Thanks in advance.

```
jbossql=# \d event_mydata
         Table "public.event_mydata"
 Column          |          Type          | Modifiers 
-----------------+------------------------+-----------
 event_id        | bigint                 | not null
 date_time       | character varying(255) | 
 secs_since_1970 | double precision       | 
 value           | real                   | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fkcf2bc134ec016855" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES event(id)
```

And List is an element collection

```
@ElementCollection
private List<MyData> myData;
public List<MyData> getMyData() {
    return myData;
}
```

Comment: how many records are usually in the myDataList collection? You retrieve the MyData collection from eventFromDb for every single MyData object you want to add. Instead you could retrieve that collection once and add all items to it. You should also check if the table holding the MyData information has an index on the foreign key for its association to the table holding the Event data. If not, that alone would explain why your method takes so long to complete.

Comment: Normally I'd say "use PgJDBC's COPY protocol support to batch-load the records" but I don't think you can really do that via JPA. It's possible that you'll have better results from doing a `getMyData().addAll(myDataList)` but it'll still land up doing a lot of tiny inserts, which will still be slow especially if you have much round-trip time between DB and appserver.

Comment: Similar one, can refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10995063/366964

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek I have changed the code your suggestion and it did not help. I start seeing the latency when there's approximately 10,000 records. The table holding the MyData has an index on the foreign key for it's association to the table holding the Event data. I have added the table description for you in my edited question above. Any idea what else i could try? When i insert the records via the psql CLI, i don't see any delay. So, it's my transactions that are to blame. Should i tweak some config to increase the heap space? But that would just be a temporary solution, i would think. Thx.

Comment: @NayanWadekar The problem is present even if i want to insert just one record. It takes in excess of 10 secs to add one record when there are more than 50,000 records. Interestingly, it's the same time i.e 10 secs to insert one or ten or twenty records. I think i should use criteriaquery to do my inserts rather than rely on entitymanager's merge as persist methods to do the work for me. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that using an ElementCollection is not a very good idea if one is thinking about populating large quantities of data.

[related issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837433/how-can-i-add-an-element-to-a-lazily-loaded-collection-in-hibernate-without-caus?rq=1)

I re-architected the database such that i am now using a one-to-many with birectional relationship. Seems to help in inserting a new entry in the child table when there is a lot of data already in the child table.

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks all for looking and responding.